# Courier Authentication Library with MySQL Authentication - Unable to configure

Tags: courier, courier-imap, mod-auth-mysql

I'm building a replica of a production server for migrating it to a Virtual environmnet. I do not want to just copy it as it is a 32 bit CentOS 5, and I upgraded it to CentOS 6 64bit.

I managed to replicate mysql and maintain it as a slave of the production one. The mailserver is managed through ISPConfig2, which I also copied.

The problem now is authentication with pop server. I installed auth-mysql library, and configure it (comparing the configuration files in the production server). I managed to get it loaded on startup, 
but it seems to be another configuration overriding it:

```
Sep  5 09:27:10 localhost authdaemond: modules="authmysql", daemons=5
Sep  5 09:27:10 localhost authdaemond: Installing libauthmysql
Sep  5 09:27:11 localhost authdaemond: Installation complete: authmysql
Sep  5 09:27:18 localhost postfix/postfix-script[1502]: starting the Postfix mail system
Sep  5 09:27:18 localhost postfix/master[1503]: daemon started -- version 2.6.6, configuration /etc/postfix
Sep  5 09:27:27 localhost authdaemond: modules="authuserdb authldap authcustom authpipe", daemons=5
```

Could it be postfix overriding it? It first loads "authmysql", and after that, starts loading "authuserdb authldap authcustom authpipe". I've been trying all the weekend, I even removed auth-ldap configuration files, but I'm now stuck.

When I login via Telnet, it even doesn't try to connect MySQL:

```
Sep  5 09:41:00 localhost pop3d: Connection, ip=[::1]
Sep  5 09:41:09 localhost authdaemond: ldap_simple_bind_s failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  5 09:41:09 localhost authdaemond: ldap_simple_bind_s failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Sep  5 09:41:09 localhost pop3d: LOGIN FAILED, user=xxx@xxx.com, ip=[::1]
Sep  5 09:41:09 localhost pop3d: authentication error: Input/output error
```

Any idea on what to try or which configuration file could be doing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. For any reason there were two configuration files "authdaemonrc" in two different dirs and I wasn't editing the correct one. Modified it, and link the correct libauthmysql.so files, and worked.